# You do not have permission to view this directory or page. error when using Azure AD to authenticate API

Tags: azure, api, authentication, permissions, bearer-token

We are receiving the following error when we try to consume one of the APIs deployed to azure:

"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Following numerous tutorials we have set up and registered an API app in azure. Then enabled AD authentication on this however looks like we are missing permission or scope which is not letting postman get access to the API even though we are passing in the access token generated from :

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token

We have noticed the access token doesn't have any sort of scope, role, permission in it. However are unsure where this has to be added, even tried adding new scope in the manifest. Looking at the diagnostic logs the "most likely cause" is specified as:

"The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request."

Access token being generated:

```
{
   "aud": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
   "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
   "iat": 1234343434,
   "nbf": 1234343434,
   "exp": 1234343434,
   "aio": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=",
   "appid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "appidacr": "1",
   "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
   "oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "sub": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "tid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "uti": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "ver": "1.0"
 }
```

Code generated by postman to get the token above:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("content-length", "195");
request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader("cookie", "fpc=AvF4ZvXAqUBPt5LOy7AEkVQIjAwtAQAAANhCb9QOAAAA; x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; stsservicecookie=ests");
request.AddHeader("Host", "login.microsoftonline.com");
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "b38e8e03-97f6-4d52-82fd-d9bec59de767,c13da490-096c-4847-8122-39d028d9625e");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.11.0");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net%2F.default&client_secret={clientSecret}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Code Generated when trying to use the access token and receive the error message:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Status/xxxxxxx");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader("cookie", "ARRAffinity=249d53bdc28cc342edb4965228850aa72a8304630357254128300b6abf863e83");
request.AddHeader("Host", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net");
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "7a9e0638-90cf-41c6-b6bf-0eea11aca929,95980a03-ef39-4c1e-af35-65bec0aaa903");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.11.0");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {bearerToken}");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Information in the call for the token will be more useful

Comment: Request generated by postman added thanks

Comment: You have not shared the call you make including headers, body, parameters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get token you need to make a **POST** call to **management.azure.com**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfr8Q.png]

A while back i put together information in the link below to help clarify steps to use RestApi (Postman in this case) to manage Azure.

https://github.com/hhazeley/Azure-Postman